# How to save a single powerpoint slide file using VSTO

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

I want to save a Slide object to a file using VSTO.
Unfortunately the slide object is non-serializable so i cannot use the standard way to save an object to a file. I tried it with the xmlserializer but no result i get keeping errors complaining that the Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide object cannot be serialized.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it should work =)

```
var temporaryPresentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Presentations.Add(Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
var targetSlide = temporaryPresentation.Slides.Add(1, Interop.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank);

foreach (Interop.Shape shape in sourceSlide.Shapes)
{
    try
    {
        shape.Copy();
        targetSlide.Shapes.Paste();
    }
    catch (Exception) { };
 }

 temporaryPresentation.SaveAs(fileName, Interop.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation, Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
 temporaryPresentation.Close();
```

Comment: Yes, i managed to save the single file in a new presentation. It works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not save a pptx file with just that particular slide in it?

Comment: Does that mean i need to create another instance of Powerpoint to create  anew application to save ?

Comment: Do you have any c# code samples ? I want the current slide to be saved, this could also be as a separate pptx file with just the one slide.

Comment: Yes, i managed to save the single slide in a new presentation.